# Read/Print non-ASCII characters using C++

Tags: c++, c++17, non-ascii-characters

How read and print the first character of this array? (Not the whole string, only first character).

```
char data[]= "£A";
printf("%c", data[0]);
```

Here, I have tried
`printf("%c", data[2]);`

Output: A

But `printf("%c", data[0]);` or `printf("%c", data[1]);` does not print anything (blank output).

Comment: Non-general way: `printf("%c%c", data[0], data[1]);`

Comment: Most likely, your source file is saved with UTF-8 encoding, where `£` requires two bytes to encode. So `data` is actually four bytes large: `data[0]` and `data[1]` together encode `£`, `data[2]` encodes `A`, and `data[3]` is `\0`, the terminating NUL character. Generally, not every Unicode character can be printed with `%c` specifier; only the first 256 can.

Comment: To add to what @IgorTandetnik said. Here's an example of the size of your _one_ letter could have: https://godbolt.org/z/7dxv9a

Comment: @TedLyngmo The size printed is the size of the character plus the size of terminating null-character.

Comment: @MikeCAT I guess you looked at my example before I adjusted just that :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Subtracting `std::size("")` may be better.

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm a bit tired right now, but that should be `1` on all standard conforming platforms. Oh, ok, to not use magic numbers? Correct - I agree.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::string String;

size_t GetTotalUTF8Chars(const String &data)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    for (char value : data)
    {
        if ((value & 0xc0) != 0x80)
        {
            ++ret;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

String GetUTF8Char(String data, size_t pos)
{
    if(pos >= GetTotalUTF8Chars(data))
    {
        throw std::length_error(u8"Invalid UTF8 character position");
    }
    String result;
    String::const_iterator it = data.begin();
    String::const_iterator beginIterator(it);
    size_t utf8pos = 0;
    if ((data[0] & 0xc0) != 0x80)
    {
        it++;
    }
    while (it != data.end())
    {
        char value = *it;
        if ((value & 0xc0) != 0x80)
        {
            if (pos == utf8pos)
            {
                return String(beginIterator, it);
            }
            beginIterator = it;
            utf8pos += 1;
        }
        it++;
    }
    return String(beginIterator, it);   
}

int main()
{
    char cstr[] = u8"HelloWorld£A";
    String str = String(cstr);

    std::cout<<"█ With C String"<<std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < GetTotalUTF8Chars(cstr); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i <<".- " << GetUTF8Char(cstr, i) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout<<"█ With C++ String"<<std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < GetTotalUTF8Chars(str); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i <<".- " << GetUTF8Char(str, i) << std::endl;
    }

  str = u8"£A";
    printf(u8"Position0 = %s / Position1 = %s\n", GetUTF8Char(str,0).c_str(), GetUTF8Char(str, 1).c_str());

  try{
    std::cout << GetUTF8Char(str, 15) << std::endl; 
  }
  catch(std::exception &ex)
  {
    std::cout<< "Exception message:" <<ex.what()<<std::endl;
  }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
█ With C String
0.- H
1.- e
2.- l
3.- l
4.- o
5.- 
6.- 
7.- W
8.- o
9.- r
10.- l
11.- d
12.- 
13.- £
14.- A
█ With C++ String
0.- H
1.- e
2.- l
3.- l
4.- o
5.- 
6.- 
7.- W
8.- o
9.- r
10.- l
11.- d
12.- 
13.- £
14.- A
Position0 = £ / Position1 = A
Exception message:Invalid UTF8 character position
```

---

**Your example**

```
str = u8"£A";
printf(u8"%s\n", GetUTF8Char(str,0).c_str());
printf(u8"%s\n", GetUTF8Char(str,1).c_str());
printf(u8"%s %s\n", GetUTF8Char(str,0).c_str(), GetUTF8Char(str, 1).c_str());
```

**Output**

```
£
A
£ A
```

You can try this code on
[Get UTF8 Char(https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/Get-UTF8-char#main.cpp)](https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/Get-UTF8-char#main.cpp)

Comment: The whole string is printed while it seems printing only `£` is requiested...

Comment: Also `printf(data);` looks dangerous (while in this case actually safe because no user-input is given there). I prefer `fputs(data, stdout);`.

Comment: `printf(u8"%s", data);` is bad because it is passing `const char8_t*` to where `const char*` is required.

Comment: I only want to print the first character, not the whole array.

Comment: @AlSajid The first letter is likely to be composed of more than one `char`.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I did not pay attention to that part, I will correct my answer.

Comment: @Joma Just to be clear, I didn't criticize your answer but I was rather trying to lower the expectations OP has.

Comment: Ok. No problem. I have corrected my fault. All in this community need quality answers.